# Can't resolve null pointer exception

Tags: android, kotlin, null, nullpointerexception, stack-trace

This is the stack trace of my app given by playstore . I can't find what is causing null pointer exception.
Everything is working fine on my device.

```
Exception java.lang.NullPointerException:
  at in.vikalp.gridforart.ui.MainFragment$onCreateView$1.invoke (MainFragment.java:192)
  at in.vikalp.gridforart.ui.MainFragment$onCreateView$1.invoke (MainFragment.java:192)
  at in.vikalp.gridforart.ui.MainFragment$sam$androidx_lifecycle_Observer$0.onChanged (MainFragment.java)
  at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.considerNotify (LiveData.java)
  at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.dispatchingValue (LiveData.java:56)
  at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.setValue (LiveData.java)
  at androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData.setValue (MutableLiveData.java)
  at androidx.lifecycle.LiveDataScopeImpl$emit$2.invokeSuspend (LiveDataScopeImpl.java:44)
  at androidx.lifecycle.LiveDataScopeImpl$emit$2.invoke (LiveDataScopeImpl.java)
  at androidx.lifecycle.LiveDataScopeImpl$emit$2.invoke (LiveDataScopeImpl.java)
  at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.DebugProbesKt.j0 (DebugProbes.kt:5)
  at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.withContext (BuildersKt__Builders_common.kt:91)
  at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.withContext (Builders.kt:91)
  at androidx.lifecycle.LiveDataScopeImpl.emit (LiveDataScopeImpl.java)
  at androidx.lifecycle.FlowLiveDataConversions$asLiveData$1$1.emit (FlowLiveDataConversions.java)
  at in.vikalp.gridforart.datastoreRepo.DatastoreRepository$special$$inlined$map$1$2.emit (DatastoreRepository.java:270)
```

this is the main fragment where the stack trace is pointing , i have also checked this but this also looks clear to me. My phone is motorola g31 with android 32 sdk . The error is coming on every type of device so it is not sdk specifice or device specific.

```
``
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainFragment : Fragment(), EasyPermissions.PermissionCallbacks {
        
 override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        _binding = FragmentMainBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this
        binding.mainViewModel = mainViewModel

        gridSettingsViewModels.readGridSettings.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onCreateView: $it")
            mainViewModel.setSettings(it)
            if (oldImageUri.toString() != EMPTY_URI)
                mainViewModel.createBitmap(oldImageUri!!)
        }

        mainViewModel.imageUriLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onCreateView: $it")
            oldImageUri = Uri.parse(it)
        }

        binding.gridButton.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(MainFragmentDirections.actionMainFragmentToGridBottomSheet())
        }

        binding.filterButton.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(MainFragmentDirections.actionMainFragmentToFilterDialogFragment())
        }

        binding.tapBarMenu.setOnClickListener {
            binding.tapBarMenu.toggle()
        }

        binding.galleryButton.setOnClickListener {
            getImageFromGallery()
        }

        binding.downloadButton.setOnClickListener {
            mainViewModel.liveBitmapReady.observeOnce(viewLifecycleOwner){
                savedImageBitmap(it)
            }
        }


        return binding.root
    }
    }
  private fun getImageFromGallery() {
        if (PermissionUtils.hasCameraPermission(requireContext())) {
            getImage.launch("image/*")
        } else {
            requestPermissions()
        }
    }

    private fun requestPermissions() {
        EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(
            this,
            "You need to accept storage permission to use this app",
            REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA_PERMISSIONS,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        )
    }

    override fun onPermissionsGranted(requestCode: Int, perms: MutableList<String>) {

    }


**-> this here is line 192** 


    override fun onPermissionsDenied(requestCode: Int, perms: MutableList<String>) {
        if (EasyPermissions.somePermissionPermanentlyDenied(this, perms)) {
            AppSettingsDialog.Builder(this).build().show()
        }
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        EasyPermissions.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults, this)
    }
``
```

Comment: The line you marked in your snippet is a blank line ... Did you review the stacktrace? It's pretty straightforward. `.emit (DatastoreRepository.java:270)` - your datastore emits a value (likely null) which goes through some conversions and gets set on live data `LiveData.setValue (LiveData.java)` which is observed in your `_Observer$0.onChanged (MainFragment.java)` which is apparently not prepared for a null value. So you need to handle null somewhere in your pipeline. If null shouldn't be possible, [debug your app](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug).

Comment: Could you provide the code of onCreateView() method?

Comment: @dominicoder thank you for your feedback but i still not understand what is causing the problem

Comment: @VikalpRanjan can you also provide the code of your ViewModel?

Comment: @MikhailGuliaev at last i managed the issue , thankyou .

Comment: I was confused because of the line number stacktrace was giving. So, i read about R8 and obfuscation and came to know that it changes the line number as well if not specified. I hope this can help someone else.  By the way the problem was i didn't null checked the livedata value in onCreate